# Proof question of integers.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab+1$ divides $a^2+b^2$.  Show that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is the square of an integer.

Comment: this looks like a vieta jumping problem :P

Comment: I googled it. Hahaha thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Numberphile did a detailed 2 part video on the question:
Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y30VF3cSIYQ
Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Vj_7Y2-xY