# Solve $\frac{A^2 + B^2}{AB + 1} = K$ for integral values of $A$, $B$, & $K$. Prove that $K$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

This question was originally asked in the 1988 IMO.  It has been answered many times and in almost as many ways.  I have not been able to find a complete and logical set of solutions this problem.

Two solution sets are known.

1) K=B^2,A=B^3.; & 
 2) K=M^2/4,B=M^3/8 .

I know how Set 1) was derived. How was Set 2) derived?

Comment: @DonlansDonlans I think this is implicit in the fact that the OP says $$\frac{A^2+B^2}{AB+1}=K$$ and $K$ is integral.

Comment: It appears what you are saying is that you have seen many solutions and understand none. Meanwhile, I put a careful proof at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188567/showing-that-m2-n21-is-a-square/2193043#2193043  The reference for this is Hurwitz (1907) http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf

Comment: LEMMA

Given integers $$  M \geq m > 0, $$ along with positive integers $x,y$ with
$$ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 = m.  $$
Then $m$ is a square.

Comment: The fraction to the left does not always yield an integer. What conditions on A, B are required? Example: A=4, B=5. Also for A=1, B=5 K is not an integer. Please add the constraints or describe the problem in full or at least mention a reference.

Comment: Yes, the complete solution is one of the first results if you google the question. The Wikipedia page for Vieta Jumping has a decent proof that you can work through. There are tons of questions already on the site. A simple search will allow you to browse them

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344722/proof-check-on-qn-6-1988-imo and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645079/prove-quotient-is-a-perfect-square and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533928/does-this-proof-for-question-6-have-a-flaw and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186630/simple-solution-to-question-6-from-the-1988-math-olympiad and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841959/proving-that-a-particular-number-is-the-square-of-an-integer

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078129/proof-question-of-integers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992951/vieta-jumping-related-to-imo-problem-6-1988-if-ab-1-divides-a2-b2-t and surely half-a-dozen others. Suggest you have a look at these, and any others linked to them, and see whether they answer your question.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250300#250300

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many solutions, but I think this solution was the most interesting.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

The Wikipedia answer is incomplete.  See edited version of original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a simple solution based on basic algebraic principles of quadratic equations.

Let,  $\frac{A^2 +B^2}{AB+1} = K$ and B = XA, where, X is a rational number (as both A and B are integers).

Then,
$\frac{A^2 +B^2}{AB+1}$ =  $\frac{A^2 + A^2X^2}{XA^2 +1}$ = $K$

This gives the following quadratic equation in X,

$A^2X^2$ -$A^2KX$ + $A^2 - K$ = $0$

As X is a rational number, sum ($A^4K^2$ - $4A^2(A^2-K)$ ) is either a perfect square or equal to zero.

(If the solution of a quadratic equation, $ax^2$ + $bx$  + $c$ is a rational number, then the term $b^2$ -  $4ac$ must be either a perfect square or equal to zero)

**Case 1:**  ($A^4K^2$ - $4A^2(A^2-K)$ ) is equal to zero

$\Rightarrow$  $A^4K^2$ + $4A^2K$ -$4A^4$ = $ 0$

$\Rightarrow$ $K$ = $ \frac{-2 \pm 2 \sqrt{2}}{A^2} $

This is not a desired solution, as K is an integer.

**Case 2:**  ($A^4K^2$ - $4A^2(A^2-K)$ ) is a perfect square

$A^4K^2$ - $4A^2(A^2-K)$ is a quadratic equation in $A^2$

Therefore,  $(K^2 - 4)A^2$ +$4KA^2$ is a perfect square,

$\Rightarrow$ Either $16K^2$ = $0$ or $4K$ = $0$(If the quadratic equation, $ax^2$ + $bx$  + $c$ is a perfect square, then one possibility is  ($b^2$ -  $4ac$) is equal to zero, the other possibility is both $b$ and $c$ are equal to zero)

$\Rightarrow$ $K$ = $0$ ; This is not a desired solution.

Reconsidering the equation $(K^2 - 4)A^2$ +$4KA^2$ and writing it in the following way,

$A^4K^2$ - $4A^2(A^2-K)$

Now, as we have exhausted the other alternatives, this equation is a perfect square only if the second term is equal to zero, or  $4A^2(A^2-K)$ = $0$.

$\Rightarrow$  $A^2$ = $K$ $\Rightarrow$ $B$ = $A^3$  (This completes the proof of the preliminary question!)

Let M be an even integer such that  M = 2A,

$\Rightarrow$ $K$ = $\frac{M^2}{4}$ and $B$ = $\frac{M^3}{8}$  (Hence both the solution sets as proposed by jllbones are the same!)